# Using ing form of verb as verb

Tags: verb-forms

The ing forms of verb are used as noun, adjective, subject or object.
Can it be used as a verb only.

Regards;

Comment: Yes, of course, that's their prime use. They occur in progressive constructions (_Ed is swimming_), and as heads of non-finite gerund-participial clauses (_Bringing your dad was a good idea_, _Who was the doctor performing the operation?_).

Answer (score 2):

We often use the -ing form with the verb-to-be to express what is *happening* or what someone or something is *doing*, that is, to express the idea of "action underway, action-in-progress".

*She was singing a ballad.*

*The sun is rising in the east.*

*The carpenter is squaring a wooden board.*

*The ship is sinking.*

*The dentist is extracting a tooth.*

*The team will be playing tomorrow.*

The verb-to-be (is, was, are, were, will be [in the case of future], et cetera) supplies the tense information to indicate whether the action-in-progress is happening now, was happening in the past, has been happening in the recent past and is still happening now, had been happening in the distant past until something changed, or will be happening in the future.

Comment: **Note to readers:** The construction @TimR is describing is commonly referred to as either the *progressive* or the *continuous* aspect. For example, "is sitting" is the *present progressive* (or *continuous*) of "to sit"; "had been sitting" is the *past perfect progressive/continuous* of "to sit," etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general (you didn't provide any details or examples), I do not think so.

As a learner, I can say that:

> A verb is a word that you can find in a Dictionary, e.g., go, buy, speak, ... and the ones that are based on them.

**verb + ing** can no longer be be a verb although it can be a part of it **<sup>†</sup>**. **verb+ ing** can be used in three ways:

1. [Gerunds](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm)
2. [Present participles](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm)
3. Adjectives
4. [Perfect participles](http://www.englishtenses.com/perfect_participle) = having + PP

Moreover, **past participles** are also based on the verbs. They are of two types

1. Regular Past Participles
2. Irregular Past Participles

However, when you use verbs for **present simple** and **past simple** tenses, you probably would have to change the verbs.

---

> **<sup>†</sup>** It is important to mention: if participles (past and present) come after **be**-verbs, they considered as a part of the verb.

Comment: @BillJ So, you say **learning** is a verb ? In this regard, what is the **is/are/was/were learning** ?

Comment: All the forms in the verb paradigm belong to the word category (part of speech) verb. The fact that the inflected forms are not listed separately in a dictionary is irrelevant. The _ing_ forms are verbs in their own right and occur in progressive constructions (_Ed is swimming_), and as heads of non-finite gerund-participial clauses (_Bringing your dad was a good idea_; _Who was the doctor performing the operation?_).

Comment: I am not native, but I am very meticulous in grammar lessons. I do not agree with you. **"he left the school, crying"** this sentence has only one verb which is **left** as well as **was** in yours.

Comment: Yes "learning" is a verb; what else could it be? The progressive aspect is formed by means of auxiliary "be" followed by a gerund-participle, the latter being very much a verb!

Comment: "Crying" is a verb. What else could it possibly be?

Comment: it is a present participle acting as an adverb!

Comment: A present participle is a verb, not an adverb. In your example, "crying" is a subordinate clause functioning as a manner adjunct. It is a common mistake with learners to confuse form and function.

Comment: So, you think your concocted sentence, **Bringing your dad was a good idea**,has two verbs. Perhaps, I should revise my studies.

Comment: You can easily tell it is a verb because it can be expanded to _crying her heart out_ where "heart" is direct object of "crying". Only verbs take direct objects.

Comment: Or maybe absolute participles ?  or adverbial participles ?
http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-clauses

Comment: Yes, _Bringing your dad was a good idea_ has two verbs. The main clause verb is "was" and the subordinate clause verb is "bringing". Note that "bringing" has a direct object "your dad". As I said, only verbs have direct objects.

Comment: "Crying" is certainly a present participle. An absolute construction is a non-finite **clause** with a noun subject and a non-finite verb, for example _His hands gripping the door, he let out a volley of curses_.

Comment: Actually, it's not really so difficult. But you must get a decent up-to-date grammar book, not a Mickey Mouse one!

Comment: @StoneyB What do you think? Why you guys create so much jargon, gerund, present participles, ... ?

Comment: @Cardinal The problem here is that there are, (a), grammatical jobs like *Subject, Object, Adjunct* (read *Adverbial*), *Determiner, Modifier, Head* and things like that. Then there are, (b), word categories like *noun, verb, adjective, adverb, determinative* and things like that. But being a Subject isn't the same as being a noun. And being an Adjunct isn't the same as  being an adverb. You are right that there is a lot of very bad and confusing terminology! :-)